# Drupal 8 - How can I override a content's template in a custom module?

Tags: drupal-8

After looking at a bunch of modules I am still confused as to how I can take a content piece I've created (a Server), make my own custom module (servers) and do some logic so I can pass that on to a servers-template.

servers.info.yml

```
name: Servers Module
description: Creates a Servers Module
package: Servers
type: module
core: 8.x
```

servers.module

```
<?php
  function servers_theme(){
   $theme['server_page'] = [
      'variables' =>['name' => NULL],
      'template' => 'server',
    ];
    return $theme;
  }
```

And I am not sure if this is correct, but my servers.routing.yml

```
servers.server:          #Pretty sure this part doesn't matter
  path: '/node/{server}' #I'd like to have /server/{server/ but my content's url is /node/xx
  defaults:
    _title: 'Servers'
    _controller: '\Drupal\servers\Controller\Servers::getServersImplementation'
    entity_type: 'server' #Not sure if this is correct
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content' #Do I need this?
```

Controller

```
#located in servers/src/controller/Servers.php
namespace Drupal\Servers\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Controller for js_example pages.
 *
 * @ingroup js_example
 */
class Servers extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * Accordion page implementation.
   *
   * We're allowing a twig template to define our content in this case,
   * which isn't normally how things work, but it's easier to demonstrate
   * the JavaScript this way.
   *
   * @return array
   *   A renderable array.
   */
  public function getServersImplementation($name)
  {
    return[
      '#theme'=>'server_page',
      '#name'=>$name,
    ];
  }
}
```

Absolutely nothing shows up when I've enabled the module. I know it's enabled because I can change the routing path to a node id /node/93 and that node will give me a page not found error, when without the routing I can get the content.

No errors are present in the error.log, or recent log messages. I am quite confused with this in D8, but once I can get this concept I know I will be able to understand all I need to complete my modules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The argument that the controller received should have the same name as the argument in the routing file. Also the entity_type is not used by this controller.

Comment: Is server a node content type? Or a new entity type?